# Can I achieve language-based badges?

Tags: support, tag-badges

If I want to achieve language-based badges then what should I do? I am new to Stack Overflow and I don't know much about badges, but I saw some people with language based badges like [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).

I also want to be like them, so is it possible for me to achieve those badges? If so, then how?

Comment: Yes you can achieve language tag based badges.

Comment: When? is it depend on my reputation?

Comment: Eeewww.. you WANT MySQL, PHP and jQuery badges?

Comment: everyone like to have those badges, but for now i just want to know can i achieve those or not. I also need those when i will make myself expert.

Comment: @FrayneKonok _"everyone like to have those badges"_ Nope :-P

Comment: sir, why not? everyone should have it.

Comment: At the clip you are going, you need to post another ~146 [php] answers or another ~266 [javascript] answers to get a bronze badge.  It's going to take a while.

Comment: @FrayneKonok _"sir, why not?"_ I'm not so involved with these tags graciously. PHP tag is a hell, like the language is itself. MySql, well my SQL fu is a bit rusty. jQuery, I'm not using javascript code most of the time. Don't call me _Sir_ BTW, I'll achieve that as offensive.

Comment: 'everyone should have it' what?  Like 'everyone should have syphilis'?

Comment: @MartinJames, achieve the language tag badges.

Comment: We expect research on Meta, too. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges

Comment: @FrayneKonok If everyone has them, nobody does. Why don't we give everyone 5000 gold badges on joining all labeled "You're awesome"?

Comment: sorry for my silly question, i just want to know about the policy how can i achieve those badges, but may be i was wrong, i don't have to ask like this question here.

Answer (score 16):

> so is it possible for my to achieve those badges??

Yes you can earn language tag based badges.

> if then how?

The [documentation from the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) says:

> > Tag Badges
> >
> > - <kbd>Bronze Badge</kbd>  You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.  87.2k awarded
> > - <kbd>Silver Badge</kbd>  You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.  16.6k awarded
> > - <kbd>Gold Badge</kbd>  You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.  5k awarded

As for your comment:

> When? is it depend on my reputation?

No, but matching the requirements from the above. Sure gaining reputation would be involved from these.

Comment: You might also mention that tag badge progress can be tracked in the "Activity" tab of one's profile.

Comment: @CodyGray I actually couldn't figure how to do that. When I searched for "python" in the available badges, it didn't come up.